# Preventing valves on ionization chamber from becoming electrified

Tags: plasma

When building ionization chamber setups, what are methods you have encountered to prevent the valve handles from becoming electrified for safety purposes?

The valves are always made of metal and, being directly exposed to the plasma, they become electrified from the plasma acting as a conductive path for the ionization voltage to reach the valves. This is the case even if the ionization voltage electrode is constructed to be isolated from everything else, or even if the bulkhead that the valve is mounted in is made of insulating materials such that it normally electrically isolates the valve.

Comment: Assuming standard tube lights, only reliable way I know is to turn off power.  Might be able to actively drive it something via a conductive connection though it may be pretty costly to do so.

Comment: @Abel Is it just a thing that you can't touch any of the valves to cut the vacuum or gas flows while ionized?

Comment: @Abel Are we talking about the same thing? It sounds like you're talking about fluorescent tubes. I'm just talking about ionization tubes for experiments and other R&D. A plain fuse quartz of borosilicate glass tube with end caps containing valves for the vacuum pump and gas tto connect to, and electrodes to apply the ionization voltage.

Comment: Yup nvm.  Today must not be one of my good days.